# Javascript: add item to Context Menu

Tags: javascript

When clicking on a particular HTML element I want a custom element to show up in the context menu which on click calls a Javascript function.

```js
// The element to whose context menu the item should be added.
const element = document.getElementById('example');

// The menu item that should be added.
const menuItem = document.getElementById('menuItem');

element.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
   //e.menuItems.add(menuItem); // How to get it into the menu?
});
```

```css
#example{border:thin solid;padding:1em;}
```

```html
<p id="example">
I want to add an item to the context menu
hat opens on this paragraph.
</p>

<!--
   the element below is supposed to show
   in the context menu instead of inline.
-->
<span
   onclick="javascript:alert('the menu item has been clicked')"
   id="menuItem">
   Click me!
</span>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem - deprecated.

Comment: @Mitya this works only in Firefox.

Comment: @AdamOrlov Perhaps you didn't see "deprecated" at the end of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add to the "real" menu, but you can fake it and without disabling the regular menu.

Listen for the context menu event, display a button in a sensible place and it will appear whenever the context menu is fired. I've placed it to the left but you could experiment with this. You then just hide it when clicked or onblur.

```js
// The element to whose context menu the item should be added.
const element = document.getElementById('example');

// The menu item that should be added.
const menuItem = document.getElementById('menuItem');

// ...so listen for the contextmenu event on this element
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
    //e.menuItems.add(menuItem); // How to get it into the menu?
    menuItem.style.left = (e.clientX - menuItem.getBoundingClientRect().width) + "px";
    menuItem.style.top = (e.clientY - menuItem.getBoundingClientRect().height) + "px";
    menuItem.style.visibility = 'visible';
    menuItem.focus();
});

// ...do this when you click the button:
menuItem.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    menuItem.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    menuItem.blur();
    alert('the menu item has been clicked');
});

// ...hide the button onblur
menuItem.addEventListener('blur', e => {
menuItem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
#example{border:thin solid;padding:1em;}
#menuItem{visibility:hidden;position:absolute;width:80px;height:35px;outline: none;box-shadow: none;}
```

```html
<p id="example">
I want to add an item to the context menu
that opens on this paragraph.
</p>

<!--
   the element below is supposed to show
   in the context menu instead of inline.
-->
<button 
   id="menuItem">
   Click me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the browser context menu without using a [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions), the best solution is to use `e.preventDefault()` which stops the browser context menu showing then adding your own context menu like popup.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items

```
"permissions": ["contextMenus"]

browser.contextMenus.create(
  {
    id: "log-selection",
    title: browser.i18n.getMessage("contextMenuItemSelectionLogger"),
    contexts: ["selection"],
  },
  onCreated
);

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "log-selection":
      console.log(info.selectionText);
      break;
    // …
  }
});
```